# Retriving All Polymorphic Relations in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**I've created polymorphic relations in my project. when i want to retrieve them like below**

```
return view('category.index')->with('categories', Category::all()) ;
```

**It returns the relations when i dd() them. However when I want to access the relation in view**

when i call it in view it gives me the following result

```
    {"id":1,"image":"abc\/abc.jpg","imageable_id":6,"imageable_type":"App\\Category","created_at":"2020-07-24T13:37:29.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-24T13:37:29.000000Z"}
```

but when i want to access the id or image index it says

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View:
> D:\WaheedSindhani\Projects\Menu\menu_proj\resources\
> views\category\index.blade.php)

i am not picking it up what is happening here

```
@if(isset($categories))
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{$loop->index+1}}</th>
                    <td>{{$category->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$category->images->image}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
```

It says no attribute named image found.
**Migration are as below**
**Images Table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('image');
            $table->unsignedInteger('imageable_id');
            $table->string('imageable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
    });

    }
```

**Menus Table**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->boolean('visible');
        $table->integer('priority');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Categories Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->boolean('visibility');
        $table->integer('priority');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Models are as follow**

```
    class Menu extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphMany( 'App\Image', 'imageable');
    }
}



class Image extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function imageable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

    class Category extends Model
{
    

    protected $guarded = [];
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }
}
```

Comment: How you `but when i want to access the id or image index it says` did this?

Comment: <td>{{$category->images->id}}</td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem occurs because the `category->images` is a `Collection` of images, not a single image. Because your relation is one to many, not one to one relationship so the soultion would be to loop over the images using a `each` loop and then do your work there.

that is why you are getting the error that you are trying to access a prop on a non-object.

```php
@if(isset($categories))
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{$loop->index+1}}</th>
                    <td>{{$category->name}}</td>

                     @foreach($category->images as $image)
                       <td>{$image->name}</td>
                     @endforeach

                </tr>
            @endforeach
@endif
```

and this concept is true for every relationship that has a `Many` in them, hasMany, belongsToMany, etc...

Comment: Huhhhhhhh Thanks for the answer. I'll complete my project today. Today was last day of it.

Comment: glad i could help, and happy coding :)]